# How do I get some other entity to rotate as me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

`execute at @p run tp @e[tag=entity] ~ ~ ~ ~ 0` rotates an entity but it teleports it to me.
Is there any way to just rotate an entity to look in the same direction without teleporting them?

Comment: if an answer helped or solved your problem, kindly accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are in the latest version(1.16.5), the following methods should work.
For a single entity(excluding players), you could do:

```
data modify entity <selector with limit=1> Rotation set from entity <selector with limit=1> Rotation
```

It is very important to add `limit=1` in the command.  For use with multiple entities(excluding players), do the following.

```
execute as <selector for the entity you want to rotate> run data modify entity @s Rotation set from entity <selector with limit=1> Rotation
```

It is important to add `limit=1` to the selectors where I said to.  For use with players and entities, you need the tp command, you can do the following.

```
execute as <selector for the entity you want to rotate> at @s rotated as <selector with limit=1> run tp @s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use
`/execute at @e[tag=entity] run tp @e[tag=entity] ~ ~ ~ ~ 0`
Change `@p` by `@e[tag=entity]` else, the tp would execute at the player

Comment: This does not answer the question